# Telinga EM23 vs Line Audio CM3 vs DPA 4060

Tags: ambience, city

Which one of the 3 is your favourite city ambience recording mic & why? any pictures of stealthy rigs using these 3 mic would be really nice guys.

Thanks!!!

Comment: hi bala, the line audio cm3 is a (semi)cardiod and therefor doesn't compare well to omni mic's. why do you want to compare these mic's specifically (besides stealth usage) ?

Comment: Hi Arnoud Traa, Im confused actually!!! I couldn't decide between the quiet telinga vs the noisy but super sounding DPA's - its the self noise issue. Any advice would be much appreciated....My aim is to get an all round ambience recording mic.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you compare different mics against each other ? I sold my cm3 because i found them absolutely useless for ambiences. They're so freaking noisy and have no detail. I bought sennheiser 8040 instead. I don't wanted to try out mics no more. I use them inside a rycote ortf ws kit. No need more to say :)
I love my dpa 4060 and i don't find them that noisy. It depends on the project. I recorded very nice ambiences with no noise because i don't gain up ambiences a lot. They're used as a low background addition. So i mostly don't get over -30db for them. No prob with the dpa's. Instead of gaining up the cm3. Wich even a sd702 can't handle well, i recommend buying the dpa4060. Superb for stealth recording and great detail. Usually i mount them inside the mesh-side bags of my camera bag. Superclean and stealthy recordings. But i would never use them for roomtones or the like. Hope this helps.  Here are some recordings of the cm3 i made also in comparision to the mkh8040 https://m.soundcloud.com/andreasusenbenz/sets/line-audio-cm3
Btw:the cm3 are really sensitive to electrical noise. I tried to record trains with them. But everywhere where electric trains where driving i got anoying noises :(

These recordings where made with my dpa4060. https://m.soundcloud.com/andreasusenbenz/sets/postcard
Good luck. Andreas

Answer (score 1):

i found a really nice recording my Jez Riley French today, which shows the capabilities of DPA4060 in field recording a forest
https://vimeo.com/115475171

Answer (score 0):

ha, well the choice IS difficult! 
i love the dpa 4060 but i would never use it in very quiet conditions. the noise floor becomes an issue quickly, but on city ambiences or indoor stuff with people, it works wonders. and it goes up to 40khz with a very linear curve. very clean sound great for pitching when recording close mic'ed sources. randy thom once said something 'any mic becomes directional if get it close enought to the source'.

i've never used the telinga's, can't you rent those and try them out? 
telinga is a pretty renowned though small company so they sell quality mic's, i read that everywhere.

the lineaudio mic's are pretty good aswell, but have low output, so you need a really good preamp (sound devices, sonosax) a h4n won't make it sound good (and adds a lot of noise). they are also good for louder ambiences and really affordable.

good luck

Comment: Thanks Arnoud Traa, regarding renting telinga - im from india & i have no source here, but as you said they have a pretty good reputation & i think i'll go with telinga as it is an all round omni with an amazing self-noise spec's. i heard some samples by Hannu Jännes from telinga's website - It sounds amazing too!!! here is the link https://soundcloud.com/hannu-jannes